# How to merge partitioned Json in Apache Nifi

Tags: json, merge, apache-nifi, dataflow

Hi I am splitting Json files of varying size from 2 GB to 3 GB.
How should I set the 'Merge content' processor such as to have the original file?
I am facing the issue of having multiple part of the same flow file after doing the merge, thi might be I am setting the limits wrong.
Do you know hot to solve this issue?
I am focusing on these properties:

-Minimum Number of Entries
-Maximum Number of Entries
-Minimum Group Size
-Maximum Group Size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reconstruct a split file you need to use MergeContent in defragment mode. I believe this ignores all of the entry and size properties and just uses the "fragment" attributes that were placed on each flow file by the split processor, and merges all the fragments back together.

Comment: As I have large data files, the problem is not all the flow files are put in queue and I don't know the last fragment. In this way it generates several groups of files instead of a single joined file

Comment: I don't understand, if you use SplitJson (or another split processor) each split flow file has fragment info, then you just tell MergeContent to Mode = Defrafgment and it waits for all fragments, the size shouldn't matter because the content is not stored in memory

Comment: But if I have multiple TextSplit in sequence wouldn't d this be a problem? as the fragment Ids are overwritten at each split

Comment: Ah yes I'm not sure if there is a great way to defragment after multiple splits, to be honest a better option might be to re-evaluate the flow and figure out if you really need to split in the first place, generally it should be avoided and many of the record processor now allow manipulation in place

Comment: Yes there is a way, using the wait notify processors, however I don't understand how to use them